# How to achieve invariable background during scene change in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Scene A and scene B have same background. If transition from A to B has animations (say, move in from left), the background will also take part in it. I do not want this. In other words, the background layer belongs neither to scene A or scene B, but something parallel to scenes and laid behind. Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think you can do this with scenes directly,
A plausible work around would be to do the following:

1. Do a scene replace with no transition
2. Set all sprite's positions to offscreen, then CCMove them into their proper places.

It's messy, but it could work.

Adam